# Run module (both as a module and) locally as script with local import

Tags: python, module, python-import

I am pretty new to python, so I might be missing (and probably am) some critical part of the import system, but I can't for the life of me figure it out at this point. I have a directory structure as follows:

```
/
/always_run.py
/lib/__init__.py
/lib/data.py
/lib/config.py
```

**File Internals (imports):**

**`/always_run.py`**

```
from lib import data
```

---

**`/lib/data.py`**

```
from lib import config
```

*yields*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\data.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lib import config as configs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

---

**Note:** I've also tried:

```
from . import config
```

*yields:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\data.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import config as configs
ImportError: cannot import name 'config'
```

---

Within `data.py` I also have:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("loading myself")
```

Just to test, but it makes no difference, it never gets to that point

---

Normally I run my program as `python always_run.py` and the world is my oyster, but if I try to run `data.py` directly I always get import failures. (after first `cd`*ing* into the `lib` directory and running `python .\data.py`

Is what I am trying to do not possible without adding the local directory to the `sys.path`, like this(test, works):

```
import sys
local_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
if local_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(local_path)
import config
```

In the process of writing this, I tested one further thing, `cd`ing to the parent directory and running `python -m lib.data` which works flawlessly. Now my question is one of curiosity, because I still can not find the answer otherwise. Is it not possible to run a local file that is part of a module from the local directory? Or must it be done from another directory?

Comment: Module != directory.

Comment: The name of the module would be, for example `data`, so what you should do is `import (name of module with path to module)`, for example if they were in the same directory all you would do would be `import data`

Comment: if I do `import config` within `data.py` then when `always_run.py` (which is in the parent directory of `data.py` and `config.py`) imports `data` it gets the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'` back from `data.py` -- so it seems I can either get imports to work locally, or externally, but not both. unless I import the local path on sys.path (see updated main quesiton)